# Sencha Touch detailed page view into items with buttons

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

1.Could please anybody help me with this issue?
1.After clicking on data detail I need see something as bellow (NotesApp.view.NoteEditor):

1.button_1
1.html + {title} + html
1.button_2
1.html + {narrative} + html

> ```
> app.js
> ```

```
Ext.application({
    name: "NotesApp",

    models: ["Note"],
    stores: ["Notes"],
    controllers: ["Notes"],
    views: ["NotesList", "NoteEditor"],

    launch: function () {

        var notesListView = {
            xtype: "noteslistview"
        };
        var noteEditorView = {
            xtype: "noteeditorview"
        };

        Ext.Viewport.add([notesListView, noteEditorView]);

    }
});
```

> ```
> NotesApp.model.Note
> ```

```
Ext.define("NotesApp.model.Note", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Model",
    config: {
        idProperty: 'id',
        fields: [
            { name: 'id', type: 'int' },            
            { name: 'title', type: 'string' },
            { name: 'narrative', type: 'string' }
        ]
    }
});
```

> ```
> NotesApp.store.Notes
> ```

```
Ext.define("NotesApp.store.Notes", {
    extend: "Ext.data.Store",
    config: {
        model: "NotesApp.model.Note",
        data: [
            { title: "Ibuprofen STDATA 200", narrative: "LIEK"},
            { title: "Ibuprofen STDATA 450", narrative: "LIEK"},
        { title: "IbuprofANIN", narrative: "LATKA"}
        ]
    }
});
```

> ```
> NotesApp.controller.Notes
> ```

```
Ext.define("NotesApp.controller.Notes", {

    extend: "Ext.app.Controller",
    config: {
        refs: {
            notesListView: "noteslistview",
            noteEditorView: "noteeditorview",
            notesList: "#notesList"
        },
        control: {
            notesListView: {
                editNoteCommand: "onEditNoteCommand"
            },
            noteEditorView: {
                backToHomeCommand: "onBackToHomeCommand"
            }

        }
    },

    slideLeftTransition: { type: 'slide', direction: 'left' },
    slideRightTransition: { type: 'slide', direction: 'right' },

    activateNoteEditor: function (record) {

        var noteEditorView = this.getNoteEditorView();
        noteEditorView.setRecord(record); 
        Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(noteEditorView, this.slideLeftTransition);
    },

    activateNotesList: function () {
        Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(this.getNotesListView(), this.slideRightTransition);
    },

    onEditNoteCommand: function (list, record) {
        this.activateNoteEditor(record);
    },

    launch: function () {
        this.callParent(arguments);
        var notesStore = Ext.getStore("Notes");
        notesStore.load();
    },
    init: function () {
        this.callParent(arguments);
    }
});
```

> ```
> NotesApp.view.NotesList
> ```

```
Ext.define("NotesApp.view.NotesList", {
    extend: "Ext.Container",
    requires:"Ext.dataview.List",
    alias: "widget.noteslistview",

    config: {
        layout: {
            type: 'fit'
        },
        items: [{
            xtype: "toolbar",
            title: "Liek",
            docked: "top",
        }, {
            xtype: "list",
            store: "Notes",
            itemId:"notesList",
            onItemDisclosure: true,
            itemTpl: "<div>{title}</div><div>{narrative}</div>"             
        }],
        listeners: [ {
            delegate: "#notesList",
            event: "disclose",
            fn: "onNotesListDisclose"
        }]
    }, 
    onNotesListDisclose: function (list, record, target, index, evt, options) {
        console.log("editNoteCommand");
        this.fireEvent('editNoteCommand', this, record);
    }
});

NotesApp.view.NoteEditor

Ext.define("NotesApp.view.NoteEditor", {

    extend: "Ext.Container",
    requires:"Ext.dataview.List",

    alias: "widget.noteeditorview",

    initialize: function () {
        this.callParent(arguments); 
    },

    config: {

    // this is working !!!

    // tpl: [
       // '<div><p>Info about: {title} </p></div>'
    // ],

        items: [
            {
                xtype: "button",
                text: '<div style="text-align:left;">button 1<div>',
                ui: "action",
                id:"button_1"
            },
            {
                xtype: 'list',
                itemTpl: [
                    '<div>title: {title} </div>' // working not !!!
                ]
            },
            {
                xtype: "button",
                text: '<div style="text-align:left;">button 2<div>',
                ui: "action",
                id:"button_2"
            },
            {
                xtype: 'list',
                itemTpl: [
                    '<div>title: {narrative} </div>' // working not !!!
                ]           
            }
        ]
    },

});
```

Answer (score 0):

in your controller, you attach the `onEditNoteCommand` handler to the `editNoteCommand`. This is not a valid event (and is never triggered) of the `Ext.dataview.List` object as you can see in the Sencha [documentation](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2.2.1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List).

You have to attach the handler to an existing event, in this case to the `itemtap` one:

```
control: {
        notesListView: {
            itemtap: "onEditNoteCommand"
        },
        ...
```

Comment: "+1 sorry, but this is not what I need."

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

You created `NotesApp.view.NoteEditor` as list, within that list you have two separate list for title and narrative and But in controller you setting data only for NoteEditor list, not for two list within NoteEditor, so that two list will not show any data because they didn't get data.

**Can do like this**

In view

Give itemId for that two list.

```
        {
            xtype: 'list',
            itemId : 'title',
            itemTpl: [
                '<div>title: {title} </div>' // working not !!!
            ]
        },
        {
            xtype: "button",
            text: '<div style="text-align:left;">button 2<div>',
            ui: "action",
            id:"button_2"
        },
        {
            xtype: 'list',
            itemId : 'narrative',
            itemTpl: [
                '<div>title: {narrative} </div>' // working not !!!
            ]           
        }
```

In controller

```
activateNoteEditor: function (record) {

    var noteEditorView = this.getNoteEditorView();
    noteEditorView.getComponent('title').setData(record.getData().title);
    noteEditorView.getComponent('narrative').setData(record.getData().narrative);
    Ext.Viewport.animateActiveItem(noteEditorView, this.slideLeftTransition);
},
```

**What you trying to do ?**

First of all `NotesApp.view.NoteEditor` is to edit note with two fields for title and narrative.

Why you have two list for title and narrative ?

What is the purpose of that list in edit screen ?